# Tkinter not being found on my python system

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I am currently using the ubuntu system 20.04 LTS which has a python 3.8 preinstalled. But in VS code i am using the python version 3.10.12 as my interpreter. Then when trying to using the turtle library i get an error saying that the Tkinter module is not found. But at the same time when using the python 3.8 as interpreter , the code works.

Have tried the below fix on terminal but doesnt work.
`sudo apt-get install python3.10-tk [This is the code and following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCmTP.png)`
[This is the terminal code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT9OQ.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: FYI, best practice for python usually involves what is called a "virtual environment" so that each application can have all the packages and libraries and specific python version it needs to run as intended: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/